# Highlight link description in vimwiki

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-markdown, plugin-vimwiki

I'm trying to customize the colorscheme [One](https://github.com/rakr/vim-one) for Markdown under Vimwiki.

I'd like to change the color of the `Description` in `[Description](URL)`.

In my `.vimrc` I have the following relevant lines:

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
  Plug 'vimwiki/vimwiki', { 'branch': 'dev' }
  Plug 'rakr/vim-one'
call plug#end()

autocmd BufWritePre *.md :%s/\s\+$//e
set termguicolors
set background=light

set nocompatible
syntax on
filetype plugin on

function! MyHighlights() abort
    call one#highlight('VimwikiLink', '3333ff', '', '')
endfunction

augroup MyColors
    autocmd!
    autocmd ColorScheme * call MyHighlights()
augroup END

colorscheme one

let g:vimwiki_global_ext = 0  "Dont treat every md file as wiki
let g:vimwiki_ext2syntax = {}

augroup vimwiki
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufReadPre,FileReadPre *.md set ft=vimwiki
  let g:vimwiki_list = [{'path' : '/home/USER/Wiki/',
                       \ 'syntax' : 'markdown',
                       \ 'auto_generate_links': 1,
                       \ 'auto_generate_tags' : 1,
                       \ 'ext' : '.md'}]
  autocmd FileType vimwiki setlocal foldcolumn=0
  let g:vimwiki_folding = 'custom'
augroup END
```

However, it changes all (Description  & URL) to one single color:

[image]

How can I change, when concealed, the `Description` color (to bold or something that stands out)?

[image]

Other possibility is to gray out all but the `Description`.

[image]

Comment: The answer is going to depend (probably) on the syntax script for vimwiki markdown.

Comment: I try to reproduce the behavior but I fail :-| Maybe could you share your vimwiki configuration and tell us what is the filetype of the document you are editing (`:set filetype?`)

Comment: Sorry, @VivianDeSmedt I forgot to share the code to call the function. I edited the question to add this. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the additions. But I'm still wondering what is the filetype of your document (what is the result of the `:set filetype?` command) and it would be good if you could share with us the vimwiki section of your `vimrc` file (I would like first to be able to reproduce the behavior you have :-) ).

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt: Document type is `vimwiki` (not Markdown). I've added all relevant info of the `vimrc` file.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll try to reproduce the behaviour first :-)

Comment: I had a first look. It seems to me that the Vimwiki syntax for link is `[[description]](link)` instead of `[description](link)`. Furthermore the Vimwiki syntax more coarse than the Markdown syntax that introduce a special highlighting group for every part of the link. A solution could be to override Vimwiki syntax with a refined version of it.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt Vimwiki default syntax for link is `[[link]]`. If you use markdown: `[description](link)`.

Comment: @Ludenticus, thanks for your feedback. It it unclear to me if it implies that you would like us to change something to the answer. How can we help you further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With these additions to the Vimwiki syntax:

`~/.vim/after/syntax/vimwiki.vim`

```
syn match VimwikiLinkDelimiter /\[\([^\\\]]*\]\)\@=/ conceal
syn match VimwikiLinkDelimiter /\(\[[^\\\]]*\)\@<=\]/ conceal
syn match VimwikiLinkDescription /\(\[\)\@<=[^\\\]]*\(\]\)\@=/
```

With these addition to the syntax you can configure the following two highlighting group to control the appearance:

- `VimwikiLinkDelimiter`
- `VimwikiLinkeDescription`

Remark: I have followed the Markdown syntax `[description](link)`

Or:

```
syn match VimwikiLinkDelimiter /\[\[[^|]*|\([^\\\]]*\]\]\)\@=/ conceal
syn match VimwikiLinkDelimiter /\(\[\[[^|]*|[^\\\]]*\)\@<=\]\]/ conceal
syn match VimwikiLinkDescription /\(\[\[[^|]*|\)\@<=[^\\\]]*\(\]\]\)\@=/
```

For the VimWiki syntax `[[link|description]]`

Comment: Vimwiki _default_ syntax is `[[Link]]` or  `[[Link|Description]]`. Markdown alternative is `[Description](Link)`.

Comment: Well, the answer for the VimWiki default syntax `[[Link]]` or `[[Link|Description]]` works. Thanks for that! However, it doesn't work with Markdown notation in `vimwiki_markdown_custom.vim`: you wrote the regex for `[[Description]](Link)`, but it should be `[Description](Link)` instead. No double brackets!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have updated the solution accordingly :-)